# Adjusting the length of each level of a tree

Tags: tikz-trees

I have the code below for a tree. However, the length of boxes were global set. I want the adjustment to be per level. Also, I don't want the letters to be double lines (Just a single line for each box as in the code).

The image of the code is here:
[image: Adjusting the length of each level of a tree]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \tikzset{
        my node style/.style={
            font=\tiny,
            top color=white,
            bottom color=blue!25,
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            minimum size=4mm,
            draw=blue!75,
            very thick,
            drop shadow,
            align=justify,
        }
    }
    \forestset{
        my tree style/.style={
            for tree={grow=east,
                parent anchor=east, % <---
                child anchor=west,  % <---
                my node style,
                l sep=1.5em,
                text width=4.6cm,
                %                   text width=5cm,
                forked edge,                % <---
                fork sep=1em,               % <---
                edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
                if n children=3{for children={
                        if n=2{calign with current}{}}
                }{},
                %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
                tier/.option=level,
            }
        }
    }
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        my tree style
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        ]
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

---

Dear js ~Bibra, Thank you so much once again. The problem is that when the text in one of the boxes on the same level is much than the other, the alignment will be poor. For instance, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{
    my node style/.style={
        font=\tiny,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!25,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        % minimum size=4mm,
        draw=blue!75,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=justify,
        % level 2/.style={text width=3.5cm},
    }
}
\forestset{
    my tree style/.style={
        for tree={grow=east,
            parent anchor=east, % <---
            child anchor=west,  % <---
            my node style,
            l sep=1.5em,
            % text width=3.5cm,  %<---turn off all sizing
            %                   text width=5cm,
            forked edge,                % <---
            fork sep=1em,               % <---
            edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
            if n children=3{for children={
                    if n=2{calign with current}{}}
            }{},
            %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
            tier/.option=level,
        }
    }
}
\centering
\begin{forest}
    my tree style
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y, text width=4cm %<---changed
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    ]
    [Inicialização de sistema Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema de sistema]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Please, see the image of the output that is not well aligned. 
[image]

Comment: `I don't want the letters to be double lines` --  what does it mean

Comment: I mean for instance for the first level, I want the output to be: Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet. I don´t want it to be: Inicialização de sistema // Acção Y Euro Pallet.

Comment: please note that the requirement has now changed  from the earlier one -- it would be courteous to upvote the answer if it meets your earlier requirement before the edit was made -- will revert regards your new requirement

Comment: I vote that the answer is useful now. I will be expecting the modified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As answered to an earlier query  global option can be used which will give the above shape

```
\forestset{
        my tree style/.style={
            for tree={grow=east,
                parent anchor=east, % <---
                child anchor=west,  % <---
                my node style,
                l sep=1.5em,
                text width=3.5cm,
                %                   text width=5cm,
                forked edge,                % <---
                fork sep=1em,               % <---
                edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
                if n children=3{for children={
                        if n=2{calign with current}{}}
                }{},
                %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
                tier/.option=level,
            }
```

Alternatively `text width` can be manipulated at a desired level by appending

```
[Inicialização de sistema Acção Y, text width=5cm
```

[image]

Better turn off all sizing options so that the nodes automatically take the minimum width--and then if required manipulate one node if required

The ultimate option is to create a separate style for a level 0, 1, 2 .... as defined in the book -- http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/texlive-doc/latex/forest/forest.pdf

### The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \tikzset{
        my node style/.style={
            font=\tiny,
            top color=white,
            bottom color=blue!25,
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            % minimum size=4mm,
            draw=blue!75,
            very thick,
            drop shadow,
            align=justify,
            % level 2/.style={text width=3.5cm},
        }
    }
    \forestset{
        my tree style/.style={
            for tree={grow=east,
                parent anchor=east, % <---
                child anchor=west,  % <---
                my node style,
                l sep=1.5em,
                % text width=3.5cm,  %<---turn off all sizing
                %                   text width=5cm,
                forked edge,                % <---
                fork sep=1em,               % <---
                edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
                if n children=3{for children={
                        if n=2{calign with current}{}}
                }{},
                %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
                tier/.option=level,
            }
        }
    }
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        my tree style
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y, text width=4cm %<---changed
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        ]
        [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        [Inicialização de sistema]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear js ~Bibra, Thank you so much once again. The problem is that when the text in one of the boxes on the same level is much than the other, the alignment will be poor. For instance, consider the following code:

Comment: i see you -- wil revert